# Pythontex/Pygments : choose an other pygopt style for inline code \py{} \pyv{}

Tags: verbatim, pythontex, pygments

I'm using a `mdframed` environment in order to add a dark background to the pythontex environments `pyverbatim`, `pyblock`, `pycode`, etc.. The code is printed with the monokai style.

For inline codes (without background), I would like to use an other style like `tango`. Would it possible to set one style for the environments `pyverbatim`, `pyblock`... and an other one for the inline version `\pyv{}, \pyc{}`... ?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,table]{scrbook}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usepackage{fvextra}
\fvset{breaklines=true,linenos=true}
\usepackage[pygopt={style=monokai}]{pythontex}
%
%\setpythontexpygopt[pycon]{style=monokai}
%\setpygmentspygopt[pyv]{style=monokai}
%tango style just for inline families ?

% Dark mode
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{bgmonokai}{RGB}{4, 44, 52}
\newenvironment{codepy}[1][]{%
   \mdfsetup{
      backgroundcolor = bgmonokai,
      hidealllines    = true,
      skipabove       = 0.2\baselineskip,
      skipbelow       = 0.7\baselineskip,
      splitbottomskip = 2pt,
      splittopskip    = 2pt,
      innerleftmargin = 8pt,
      innertopmargin  = 2pt,
%      frametitlealignment={\hspace*{-50pt}}
      }
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\begin{mdframed}
    }{
    \begin{mdframed}[
    frametitle   = {\color{white}\texttt{\tbf{#1}}}]
    }
    }{\end{mdframed}%
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{codepy}
\begin{pyconsole}
x = 1
x + 1
\end{pyconsole}
\end{codepy}

\begin{codepy}
\begin{pyverbatim}
x = 1
y + 1
\end{pyverbatim}
\end{codepy}

We don't see this text : \pyv{numpy}. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workaround modifies the `\pyv` command to set the internal style macro `\pytx@style` before and after the command. The redefinition is placed after `\begin{document}` because `\pyv` is not yet defined in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt,table]{scrbook}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\usepackage{fvextra}
\fvset{breaklines=true,linenos=true}
\usepackage[pygopt={style=monokai}]{pythontex}
%
%\setpythontexpygopt[pycon]{style=monokai}
%\setpygmentspygopt[pyv]{style=monokai}
%tango style just for inline families ?

% Dark mode
\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{bgmonokai}{RGB}{4, 44, 52}
\newenvironment{codepy}[1][]{%
   \mdfsetup{
      backgroundcolor = bgmonokai,
      hidealllines    = true,
      skipabove       = 0.2\baselineskip,
      skipbelow       = 0.7\baselineskip,
      splitbottomskip = 2pt,
      splittopskip    = 2pt,
      innerleftmargin = 8pt,
      innertopmargin  = 2pt,
%      frametitlealignment={\hspace*{-50pt}}
      }
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
    {\begin{mdframed}
    }{
    \begin{mdframed}[
    frametitle   = {\color{white}\texttt{\tbf{#1}}}]
    }
    }{\end{mdframed}%
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\oldpyv\pyv
\def\mypyv#1{\def\pytx@style{tango}\oldpyv{#1}\def\pytx@style{monokai}}
\let\pyv\mypyv
\makeatother

\begin{codepy}
\begin{pyverbatim}
x = 1
y + 1
\end{pyverbatim}
\end{codepy}

We don't see this text : \pyv{self.var = var}.

\begin{codepy}
\begin{pyverbatim}
x = 1
y + 1
\end{pyverbatim}
\end{codepy}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the workaround does not allow for optional arguments to `\pyv`.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly ! I tried the command `\AfterEndPreamble{\makeatletter
\let\oldpyv\pyv... }` but it has no effect.